# How to implement an app which can be two apps or one?

Tags: delphi

To clarify:

1. I want to collect data from from a hardware sensor and display it on a PC in the location in which it is collected.
2. I want to do some data-mining and show the results on a PC which may or may not be co-located.

So, some folks might want both functionalities in one location and some in two.

What's the best way to provide this, given that there will probably be some shared code?

Two separate apps, or one app which can display functionality A, B or A & B deepening on the customer?

If one app, what would you use to display two windows? Side by side, Tabsheet or what?

Or does it just depend on the piece of string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use separate apps.  A non-visual service running in the background collecting the data, and a viewer app to display it to users.  The viewer app can then run on the local machine and remote machines, all making connections to the service to receive data updates.

Comment: Remy, a great idea. I hadn't thought of that, but it certainly makes sense. Any tips on how to implement before I award the answer? And, how would you display, if at one locaion - assuming that the 2 apps have differnt displays - in one app with tabsheet, with two separate windows, in two independant apps, each of which can be run indeendantly?  Thanks a  1,000,000 for your help (+)

Comment: Unless the data mining has a lot of overhead that should be in its own process, I would probably just use one app with a TabSheet, with each tab displaying a different view of the same data. The service is its own process, collecting the sensor data, pushing data updates to clients, and storing a local cache of the latest data so new clients can receive the current data before the next update. The viewer receives a single copy of data updates and processes it however it needs. I would use TCP or named pipes to connect to the service, as both are network-capable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB Named pipes are a real PITA over networks, thanks to latest Windows security policies. TCP or HTTP are much easier to use on the customer side, according to my experiment.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented already some very close software solution in Delphi for a complex biological analysis automated device.

I see at least two implementation patterns:

*1 - You can have the same Delphi executable being at the same time:*

- A background service application;
- A GUI application.

Be aware that in this case, two instances of the executable will be executed. So you can't just share variables between the two part of the code easily, will have to rely on some IPC mechanism: GDI messages are light and fast but are not allowed since Vista for a service application, so I guess that a named pipe will be the right candidate.

Advantage: The service part will run on the background, even before the User will have opened its windows session (this make sense for a background hardware task).

Disadvantage: more complex IPC to implement.

But if you make the IPC protocol network ready, you will be able to consult all your data remotely: you can have your client application deployed on the network, even through the Internet if necessary. Or you may deploy an Ajax application, if you use publish e.g. some JSON or HTML content over HTTP.

(I've used this design for my automated device, with a [HTTP/1.1 Client-Server ORM](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Downloads) to share the same classes between the client and the server).

*2 - You can have one Delphi executable being on the same time a background application and a GUI application.*

To implement this:

- Overwrite the `OnClose / wmClose` event to disallow closing of the form - minimize it in tray instead;
- Create a semaphore to localize an existing application: so when you launch another time the .exe, it will restore the main application;
- The tray icon would have a menu or restore the application by a double click;
- Create a background thread to process all the measures - use a loop with a `Sleep` call.

Comment: methinks what using HTTP for communicating daemon and GUI is kinda overkill.

Comment: @PrematureOptimization Of course, that is why I stated that since GDI messages are not permitted any more, my first advice was to use a named pipe. Then HTTP for remote GUI access over a network: named pipes are much less network friendly than HTTP, due to some security policies of Windows (depending on the OS used) and your firewall / network settings.